# How to read data from Cosmos Db emulator in Unit test case

Tags: unit-testing, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-emulator

I am writing unit test cases and would like to read data from Cosmos Db emulator. I have achieved this far and would need help in reading data now from Emulator. How can I read data from container where lets say I have data with Id = "Test"

```
public class DataFixtures
{
    public DataFixtures()
    {
        app.CreateDefaultLoggerFactory();
    }
}


[CollectionDefinition("Tabulardata collection")]
public class DataCollection : ICollectionFixture<DataFixture>
{
}



[Collection( "Tabulardata collection" )]
public class DataTests
{
    private static readonly string CosmosEndpoint = "https://localhost:8081";
    private static readonly string EmulatorKey = "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==";
    private static readonly string DatabaseId = "Recordings";
    private static readonly string RecordingCollection = "testdata";
    string Root = Directory.GetParent( Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() ).Parent.Parent.FullName;


    private void ReadConfig()
    {
        var client = new DocumentClient( new Uri( CosmosEndpoint ), EmulatorKey,
            new ConnectionPolicy
            {
                ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
                ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Tcp

            } );
        var databaseCreationResult = client.CreateDatabaseAsync( new Database { Id = DatabaseId } ).Result;
        var collectionCreationResult = client.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync( UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri( DatabaseId ),
            new DocumentCollection { Id = RecordingCollection } ).Result;            
    
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this?

```
private void ReadConfig()
    {
        var client = new DocumentClient( new Uri( CosmosEndpoint ), EmulatorKey,
            new ConnectionPolicy
            {
                ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
                ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Tcp

            } );
        var databaseCreationResult = client.CreateDatabaseAsync( new Database { Id = DatabaseId } ).Result;
        var collectionCreationResult = client.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync( UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri( DatabaseId ),
            new DocumentCollection { Id = RecordingCollection } ).Result;

var docUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(DatabaseId, RecordingCollection, "Test");
    var response = await client.ReadDocumentAsync(docUri,
            new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("partitionkey_value") });
        Console.WriteLine("Document read by Id {0}", response.Resource);          
    
    }
```

Refer to [this tutorial](https://docs.azure.cn/zh-cn/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.readdocumentasync?view=azure-dotnet) and this [sample code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v2/blob/master/samples/code-samples/DocumentManagement/Program.cs#L162).

This is my testing result:

[image]

Comment: where should I put it? Should it be under Readconfig

Comment: @ZZZSharePoint Just below `var collectionCreationResult = client.CreateDocument.......`